# Is there any command to get the opportunity list of PowerShell version from PowerShell command prompt?

Tags: powershell, command-line, system-administration

Is there any command (or command set) to get the opportunity list of PowerShell version from PowerShell command prompt?

I've solved this question. It is possible to overview the newest features by command `Get-Help about_Windows_PowerShell_5.0`.

Comment: Hello! I've solved this question. It is possible to overview the newest faetures by command `Get-Help about_Windows_PowerShell_5.0`. So my question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The `$PSVersionTable` variable contains information about the PowerShell environment. If you look at `$PSVerstionTable.PSVersion` it will give you the version of PowerShell.